# Is there a simple proof for Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying two abstract algebra texts simultaneously now, namely, 'Dummit&Foote' and 'Fraleigh'.

Both of these texts introduce 'Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated abelian group' without proof and assume this true for some moment and it is said there that the general result will be given in later chapter.

I hate this aspect since this approach can possibly make one to forget what is deduced from what, then make one fall in cycle-logic.

I heard that, in Germany, this kind of approach is not in favor.

Is there a simple proof for it?

Comment: It has to be simpler than the one appearing in D+F? I would think they would provide a fairly simple proof.

Comment: if $G$ is finite, http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups it is short and depending on induction, for general case you can see this; http://math.arizona.edu/~savitt/teaching/07math511a/fin_gen_ab_gps.pdf

Comment: Try Serge Lang's *Algebra* or Michael Artin's *Algebra*.

Comment: I don't know a simple proof, but you can study finitely generated modules over PID